# Exporting multiple municipality Quarter Sections

Tags: arcpy

I am very new to python and am attempting to select a municipalities pipe data by their QS number(in attribute table), dissolve the feature class on objected and qs# then export to a .gdb. I can do this one at a time but it requires me to reenter the QS number in parts of the script. I would also like the exported feature class to have a name like "QS_01_27", "QS_1-31" etc depending on the qs name. So I guess in short I would like to:

1. Select qs from dataset
2. dissolve qs on objectID, qs#
3. export to a .gdb with a unique name

This needs to be repeated for 689 quarter sections. below is what I have been stuck on and what I have started.

```
#Import system modules 
import arcpy
import os

#Set workspace and mxd
workspace = "R:/desktop/this.gdb
mxd = "R:/desktop/this.mxd" 

#set Variables 
fc = "ProjectSewerMains"  
outfc = "QS01_27" 

#Select layer by QS 
arcpy.Select_analysis("fc","outfc", """ QSNO = '01-27' """)

#Dissolve
arcpy.Dissolve_management(outfc, " ",     ["OBJECTID", "QSNO"], " ", "MULTI_PART", "DISSOLVE_LINES")
```

Comment: Do you have QS numbers in a list?

Comment: I have them in an excel file. I brought that into ArcMap but could not figure out how to reference it in Python.

Comment: What about dissolve fields(objectid-qs#). Do you have it in a separate excel file?

Comment: I do not but that would be easily achieved

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you saved data in the excel and your FC. I gave you an example with my own data. I used "Blocks" feature class in the "Montgomery.gdb". It's one the "Building Geodatabase" tutorial data esri published for users.You need to convert the excel to a csv file. Read and follow my comments in the code.

[image]

I created a field and named it "Test2" with number values of 1 and 2 (The below image).

[image]

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy, os, csv
# Set workspace. Replace my workspace with yours.
arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:\...\ArcTutor9\BuildingaGeodatabase\Montgomery.gdb"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
# Create an output gdb
outputgdb = "D:/dissolve.gdb"
# set the directory of csv file.
txt = "D:/Mytxt.csv"
# Read CSV file and put all of the values in a list
with open('D:/Mytxt.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    mylist = list(reader)
print mylist
# set feature class name. Replace my fc with your source fc ("ProjectSewerMains")
fc = "Blocks_1"
# use the number variable for output names. Example: QS_01_1, QS_01_2 , ...
number = 1
# Loop your list and use the values for query (Note: '{0}'.format() ) . Your list is a nested list then you need to
# use two loops. It's not the best solution because of the performance.
for l1 in mylist:
    for l2 in l1:
        # Select layer by your field (QS). I used "Test2". In the Test2 I just have "1" and "2" numbers.
        arcpy.Select_analysis(fc, os.path.join(outputgdb, "QS_01_{0}".format(number)), '"Test2" = {0}'.format(l2))
        number += 1
        print "{0} feature class successfully created".format(l2)

# Dissolve

# Set output workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = outputgdb
# List all of feature classes in the output ws
listfc = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

# use os.path.join to join the output gdb and output fc .
for lf in listfc:
    desc = arcpy.Describe(lf)
    print desc.baseName
    if "Dissolved" not in desc.baseName:
# Add your own fields in arcpy.Dissolve_management. I just add "OBJECTID".
        arcpy.Dissolve_management(lf, os.path.join(outputgdb, lf + "Dissolve"), ["OBJECTID"], " ", "MULTI_PART",
                                  "DISSOLVE_LINES")
        print "{0} dissolved successfully".format(lf)
```

The result is like the below image:

[image]

Comment: Hitting a snag in the loop. For the "number = 1" and "number += 1" seems to be throwing an error. More specifically "number +=1"

Comment: What's the error number and description? number +=1 means 1+1 = 2,  2+1 = 3, 3+1 = 4 and so on. It's a trick in programming.

Comment: I am getting "there's an error in your program: Invalid Syntax"

Comment: Getting an error on the number += 1 line. The word number is being highlighted red.

Comment: I don't have any error with this code. I try it now. What type of error exactly you faced with? can you copy and paste the error message? what's your python IDE?

Comment: I am running Python 2.7.13 from win32

Comment: Open Arcmap. Copy your code and paste in the python window in the arcmap.

Comment: @greg I think something is wrong in your inputs. Please add an image  of csv file in your question.

Comment: "25-28"," 26-28"," 01-27"," 01-21"," 01-23"," 01-25"," 01-28"," 01-29"," 01-30"," 01-32"," 01-33"," 02-22"," 02-23"," 02-25"," 02-27"," 03-27"," 03-28"," 02-21"," 02-28"," 02-29"," 02-30"," 03-21"," 03-29"," 03-22"," 03-25","                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 It looks like this when I open in notepad from excel.